# Sitecore folder & IIS permissions

Tags: iis, sitecore, directory-permissions

When setting up or moving a Sitecore solution, you have to remember to setup the correct folder permissions and IIS permissions.

It something like sections 3.3.3.2 - 3.3.3.9 here:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%205,-d-,3/Installation/EXE%20Installation.aspx

The folder permissions are usually setup when using the installer, but not when using the Zip or just moving an existing solution.

You could use the guides (for Sitecore 6) here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/Installation.aspx

But going through steps 3.5 to 3.6.5 is bothersome.

Anyone made any scripts or programs that could do this more or less automatically?

It will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are playing around with a non-production instance:

> in non-production environments, it‘s generally easiest to grant the ASP.NET account and the anonymous Internet user account Full Control of the Website and Data folders as well as all their descendants and grant the NETWORK SERVICE user full control of D:\Sitecore\Databases folder.

So (The permissions are set recursively):

ASP.NET account (IUSR in IIS 7) & Anonymous user: FULL CONTROL OVER:

- `/Website`
- `/Data`

NETWORK SERVICE (default SQL Server account): FULL CONTROL OVER:

- `/Databases`

**Alternatively** you could [**Cacls**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls) to set permissions to a file/folder from the commandline.

*For example you could use the following statement to grant the `Administrator` user `Write` AND `Delete` permissions on `c:\file`*

```
icacls c:\file /grant Administrator:(D,WDAC)
```

Comment: Yeah non-production environment is easy enough, the problem lies in production environment, where you want it to be setup properly.

But I'll try looking into icacls/cacls/SetACL, so thanks. I'll give you an answer and hope for more help.

Now if only someone already had made a script using one of those tools for Sitecore :)

Answer (score -1):

I am using this script

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, path

' get current directory
set fso = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path = fso.GetFolder(".").Path

WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "Setting up rights"
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Path:" &  path

Dim appname

appname = InputBox("Name of the App Pool", , "AppPool")

If appname = "" Then
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Dim wsShell

Set wsShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.Shell")

'wsShell.run "icacls """+ path + """ /inheritance:r"
wsShell.run "icacls """+ path + """ /inheritance:e /grant ""IIS AppPool\" + appname + """:(RX)"
wsShell.run "icacls """+ path + "\App_Data"" /inheritance:e /grant ""IIS AppPool\" + appname + """:(F)"
wsShell.run "icacls """+ path + "\sitecore\shell"" /inheritance:e /grant ""IIS AppPool\" + appname + """:(F)"
wsShell.run "icacls """+ path + "\temp"" /inheritance:e /grant ""IIS AppPool\" + appname + """:(F)"
wsShell.run "icacls """+ path + "\upload"" /inheritance:e /grant ""IIS AppPool\" + appname + """:(F)"

set wsShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Please consider adding a explanation to your answer.