# Request for Sitecore page returns IIS 404

Tags: iis-7, sitecore, sitecore6

I request a page in Sitecore and I get a 404 from IIS.  The site works on my development environment & staging.  This is on the production machine, which is a new install.  I've never actually seen it work.  The fact that it's giving me an IIS 404 (instead of a Sitecore 404) seems to indicate that whatever handler Sitecore uses isn't being recognized or isn't set up properly.  I'd appreciate any suggestions about where to begin looking or what the issue might be.

We're in II7 running in classic mode.

Comment: /sitecore/login/ Works just fine, BTW.  It's requests to the public site that don't work.

Comment: Actually, scratch that..../sitecore/login works okay in content mode, but in desktop mode, when I click "Content" it returns an IIS 404. I notice that that request is for a "handled" item ( /sitecore/shell/sitecore/content/Applications/Content%20Editor?ic=People%2f16x16%2fcubes_blue.png), so this really feels like a handler config issue.

Comment: What version of Sitecore? Have you made any changes to the `web.config`? How did you install it, via the Wizard or manually via a .zip?

Comment: I didn't install it...it's been on this server for a while.  Also, I didn't make any changes to the web config, and it's nearly identical to the config in staging and my local.  I'll find out if there's a version conflict of some kind, but I can tell you that the dev/staging/prod versions of the site are identical...thanks.

Comment: I guess, to be clear, the one difference in the web.config between staging and prod is the path specified for the data folder.

Comment: Is there a file in the App_browser directory (can't remember the name, but there should only be one). If that is missing, a lot of stuff wont work

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues if I run Sitecore in classic mode. Why don't you try running in Integrated mode, for all handlers to work propperly? Your Sitecore login page works, so that indicates that you have unzipped the Sitecore folder corretly. I'd suggest you to try Integrated mode.

Comment: There are issues - non-sitecore related - created when we run in integrated mode.  For what it's worth, we do have another site on the sme box running in classic mode.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions issue, check that Network Service (or Application Pool Identity) has the correct access to all of the Sitecore folders.

This looks like a fairly good guide on this:

[Sitecore folder & IIS permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156374/sitecore-folder-iis-permissions)

You could also try exporting the IIS setup for production and staging and comparing the two to make sure nothing odd with the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the installer?  If you are cleaning up someone else's install, there's no telling what they did... far easier to start again.  You can easily connect to an existing database, or install a package with all your content once you've got a good working Sitecore instance.

Comment: I'm reluctant to do this on a production machine.  There's already one sitecore site running there, and I'd be concerned we'd do something to that install.  Thanks.